# google maps javascript api . Failed to load resource net error timed out

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display the google maps javascript api on an html page but it is not showing and is giving me the error "failed to load resource net::err_timed_out" 
I generated an api key on google cloud platform and put it in the script but still isnt working .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
   /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
  #map {
    height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
    width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
   }
</style>
```

```
<!--The div element for the map -->
<div id="map" </div>
<script>
 // Initialize and add the map
  function initMap() {
        / The location 
  var location = {lat: 36.512483,lng: -115.064985};
     // The map, centered at location
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
  document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 8, center: location});
    // The marker, positioned at location
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: location, map: map});
   }



</script>
<!--Load the API from the specified URL
* The async attribute allows the browser to render the page while the API loads
* The key parameter will contain your own API key (which is not needed for this tutorial)
* The callback parameter executes the initMap() function
-->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAnW5hF37VGcliSVTP7NRMS2Mz8kGORvEQ&callback=initMap" ></script>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is the error appearing? Is the error referring to your webpage, the linked script, or something else?

Comment: Your map div is missing a closing angle bracket. Is this html page on a https or localhost? make sure it is on https or localhost and in Google console you have given permission.

Comment: the error is referring to the linked script